# driver.close() is not closing the window

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation, webdriver

I am trying to close the window using `driver.close()` code but it's not working
BUt if I am closing with `driver.quit()` then it's closing but i am getting Test in Red Color . May be it is an Exception or Error but i am not sure. 
Below is the message which i am getting

```
Sep 08, 2015 2:30:26 PM org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog destroyHarder
INFO: Command failed to close cleanly. Destroying forcefully (v2). org.openqa.selenium.os.UnixProcess$SeleniumWatchDog@48cff89c
```

My firefox version is  : 40.0.3
selenium Jar is  : "selenium-server-standalone-2.46.0"

Comment: I think selenium 2.46 does not support firefox 40 version. Did you try with other browser?

Comment: No i didn't tried for other Browsers

Answer (score 1):

Use updated jars 2.47.1 is available now(Update server + binding both jars):-

```
http://docs.seleniumhq.org/download/
```

One thing one if you are switching between any pages then you need to switch back on same page to close that page with driver.close();

Comment: yes In the Scenarios (Switching page concept and in simple script).. driver.close() was not working